# Empty PageView Builder with (Future)List

Tags: flutter, sqlite, flutter-pageview

My `PageView.Builder` does not build after loading a list from my SQLite database:

```
class _PferdeWidgetState extends State<PferdeWidget> {
  DB_Pferde databaseHelper = DB_Pferde();
  late List<PferdModel> pferdeliste = [];
  final pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (pferdeliste.isEmpty) {
      updateListView(pferdeliste);
    }
  }

  Future<void> updateListView(pferdeliste) async {
    Future<List<PferdModel>> pferdeListFuture = databaseHelper.getAllPferde();
    List templist = await pferdeListFuture;
    setState(() {
      pferdeliste = templist;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView.builder(
              controller: pageController,
              itemCount: pferdeliste.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final pferd = pferdeliste[index];
                return PferdWidget(pferde: pferd);
              },
              onPageChanged: (index) => setState(() => pageIndex = index),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            '${pageIndex + 1}/${pferdeliste.length}',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white70),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 12)
        ],
      );
}
```

`updateListView` receives the necessary items but the page view builder remains invisible even when I added a `dataLoading` boolean checking if it's true before building.

Comment: please put loader while loading item and after that change flad also provide more info ss or other code

Comment: what do you mean? sorry i don't unterstand your request